# Open app settings from new button

Tags: android

I have remove the default action bar from the top of my app and replaced it with my own custom top menu. This solved a lot of problems for what I was trying to achieve with my app.

The only problem now is that I can not access the default settings button that was on the action bar. I was going to create my own settings pop up but I am not sure how without having a new activity start as a pop up dialog. This is not the same as the default settings menu popup.

Is there a way I can replicate this with my custom action bar across the top?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17872878/1777090)

Answer (score 0):

use this code in on button listener

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DialogFragment with a custom Dialog that mimics the settings pop up.

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CustomDialog dialog = CustomDialog(getActivity());

        // Position the dialog window below your action bar
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
        lp.y = 100; // action bar height
        window.setAttributes(lp);

        return dialog;
    }

    private class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

        public CustomDialog(Context context) {
            super(context);

            // do not show the title of the dialog box and dismiss
            // it if touched outside, as the normal settings pop up
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            // your custom layout
            setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout);
        }

    }
}
```

Then show it with:

```
CustomDialogFragment popup = new CustomDialogFragment();
popup.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
```